# Fluid table with td nowrap & text-overflow?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is my problem HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100%;overflow:hidden">
      <div style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;">long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is what I wanted:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;width:100%">long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
</div>
```

That is:

1. No horizontal scroll bars
2. `div` do not make the `table` and `td` so wide
3. resizing browser window makes the `div` dynamic change of `ellipsis`

btw, anyway to minic `text-overflow` on Firefox?

Comment: There's an alternative approach in this answer on [how to mix text-overflow and table cells using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569436/css-constrain-a-table-with-long-cell-contents-to-page-width).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Edit: fixed this myself using CSS:

```
table { table-layout:fixed; width:100%; }
```

Comment: I had the same width issue on my table's tds and table-layout:fixed solved it 
thanks .

Answer (score 26):

Rather than using `table-layout: fixed;` for your table, you can use this trick to get a DIV to always take up the full space of a TD with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` functionality:

```
div { width: 0; min-width: 100%; }
```

The main trick is giving the **width** something other than auto/percent, and using a min-width of 100%;

```
div { width: 0; min-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; }
table.myTable { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid #000; }

td.td1 { width: 100%; min-width: 50px; }
td.td2 { width: 100px; min-width: 100px; }
td.td3 { width: 150px; min-width: 150px; }

td.td4 { width: 50%; min-width: 50px; }
td.td5 { width: 50%; min-width: 50px; }
td.td6 { width: 150px; min-width: 150px; }
```

The table can be fluid sized or fixed width. Just give some min-widths for contents as needed.

```
<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="td1"><div>Very very very long text Very very very long text Very very very long text Very very very long text</div></td>
        <td class="td2"><div>Content 2</div></td>
        <td class="td3"><div>Content 3 also so very lonnnnngggg</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="td4"><div>Very very very long text Very very very long text Very very very long text Very very very long text</div></td>
        <td class="td5"><div>Content 2 has very very very many texts in a very very very long way</div></td>
        <td class="td6"><div>Content 3</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpa7hb1j/)

Comment: Perfect - I'd argue none of the other questions meet the "fluid" requirement

Comment: This has been tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and down to IE8. Not sure about earlier versions without some help there. iPad Safari works great, too.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and feels more flexible than the `table-layout: fixed` solution (I don't like the constraint of having to set widths for each column). Thank you.

Comment: I know you're excited @momomo, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Comment: @FrankerZ And we are all adults here. Using profane language is valid at times. It does impart anger and frustration much better than using a word like 'freaking'. I dream of a world were the internet is free from moderators and censorship. One day. But that's another topic.

Comment: Awesome, you're the champ

Answer (score 5):

My full example :

```
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            width:100%;
            table-layout:fixed;
        }
        td {
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>CHAMPIONNAT</td>
            <td>CHAMPIONNAT</td>
            <td>CHAMPIONNAT</td>
            <td>CHAMPIONNAT</td>
            <td>CHAMPIONNAT</td>
            <td>CHAMPIONNAT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me,

```
<style type='text/css'>
table {
 white-space: normal;
}
</style>
```

worked...