# CSS: Constrain a table with long cell contents to page width?

Tags: css

Take the following CSS+HTML:

```
<style>
    div.stuff {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    table { width: 100%; }
    td { border: 1px dotted black; }
</style>

<table>
    <tr><td>
        <div class='stuff'>Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text</div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

This causes the table to grow to accommodate the entire long text. (Make your browser window smaller to see if you have a humongous screen resolution.)

I added `width: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` to indicate that the long text should simply be cut off, but it seems to ignore that. How do I constrain the table/the table cell/the div in such a way that the table’s width does not exceed the width of the document?

(Please don’t comment on the merits of using a table at all. I am indeed displaying tabular data, so the use of a table is semantically correct. Also please don’t question the user-friendliness of cutting off the text; there is actually an “expand” button that allows the user to view the full contents. Thanks!)

(Edit: I tried `max-width` too, to no avail.)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To achieve this, you have to wrap the long text into two divs. The outer one gets `position: relative` and contains only the inner one. The inner one gets `position: absolute`, `overflow: hidden`, and `width: 100%` (this constrains it to the size of the table cell).

The table-layout algorithm now considers those table cells empty (because absolutely-positioned elements are excluded from layout calculations). Therefore we have to tell it to grow that column regardless. Interestingly, setting `width: 100%` on the relevant `<col>` element works, in the sense that it doesn’t actually fill 100% of the width, but 100% minus the width of all the other columns (which are automatically-sized). It also needs a `vertical-align: top` as otherwise the (empty) outer div is aligned middle, so the absolutely-positioned element will be off by half a line.

Here is a full example with a three-column, two-row table showing this at work:

CSS:

```
div.outer {
    position: relative;
}
div.inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    vertical-align: top;
}
col.fill-the-rest { width: 100%; }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <col><col><col class="fill-the-rest">
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>fooofooooofooooo</td>
        <td>
            <div class='outer'>
                <div class='inner'>
                    Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>barbarbarbarbar</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>
            <div class='outer'>
                <div class='inner'>
                    Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text Some more long text
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this example, the first two columns will have the minimum possible size (i.e. spaces will make them wrap a lot unless you also add `white-space: nowrap` to them).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLX4q/

Comment: Very nice solution and explanation. It's worth pointing out that `div.inner { width: 100%; }` is the relevant part - without that setting `overflow` will not do anything and the inner `<div>` will just bleed out to the right. Additionally, [`text-overflow: ellipsis;` is now widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=ellipsis) and should be set at the inner `<div>` for a nicer effect than just clipping the text.

Comment: I had to give my outer class a height to make this work. Also had to set the margin to auto, and top and bottom to 0 to make this work. I have some padding on my td's so I think that was causing the issue

Comment: Is there a way to make this allow for dynamic heights? For example, I want to have an indefinited number of stacked divs inside of the table cell, but I want each div to overflow based on width. 

Your example takes the width of the 'outer' div out of the table cell calculation, but it doesn't seem to treat height in the same manner; the height of cell is dictated by the max height of others in the row (just like the width is dictated by others in the column), but overflow-y does not behave in the same manner as overflow-x.

Comment: THANK YOU!! amazing solution, just working perfect! saved my day :)

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different answer: If you'd prefer the table to display all its contents, while still being constrained to the page width, try using `overflow-wrap: anywhere`. This forces text to wrap, breaking on word boundaries when possible.

To support older browsers, you can use the legacy `word-break: break-word` with `word-break: break-all` as a fallback.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/joseph_white3/nhj9fLrw/

Also note: only set `table-layout: fixed` if you want the column widths to be determined based on just the first row. See the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).

Answer (score 1):

> I added width: 100% and overflow: hidden to indicate that the long text should simply be cut off, but it seems to ignore that.

It's not ignoring that, your div is expanding 100% the width of your table, which is set to expand 100% as it is, just give your td a max-width and it should cutoff as you expect.

Comment: was that not the effect you're looking for? -- I added width: 100% and overflow: hidden to indicate that the long text should simply be cut off, but it seems to ignore that. --

Comment: here is a demo i wrote up to answer another question here in SO, http://jsfiddle.net/caq8F/5/, it has a div inside a td expanding 100% with overflow-x enabled.

Comment: “was that not the effect you're looking for?” — No, of course not; what if the page is 500px wide? 1000px? One would have thought that 100% should mean 100%...

Comment: Ok, so, at what point do you want the text to cutoff? you have to think about that, 100% width is not being very specific.

Comment: Also, 100% of what? Width is relative to the parent, if you have a table that is 500px wide, 100% of 500px is 500px, if you're referring to the body tag, 100% is the width of the content, if you're referring to the html tag, 100% width is the size of everything available in the content, you have to define 100%.

Comment: This is the best answer. Making the td's push out of the table is a lame solution. It's also less markup/css.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @Timwi's solution...

```
table {
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td {
 padding: 14px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.outer {
 position:relative;
 height: 22px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
          this_is_a_really_long_string_of_text
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      222222222
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 so that's where the height value is coming from. Here's a link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YFCV6/

Answer (score 0):

you have nowrap set so the td cannot properly constrain the content. Removing that value should achieve the desired result.

Comment: No, removing that value will make the text wrap.

Comment: oh my bad I didn't realize you wanted the text cut off - sorry. Did you try setting your td to overflow:hidden ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have any width: 100% tags, it going to expand to contain the content.

One way to get the desired result (text that does not wrap) is to have an outer div w/ overflow hidden + a set width, then an inner div with a super wide width.

http://jsfiddle.net/xvaEw/

Comment: You can do that without using an outer div at all: just constrain the inner div to that size.