# HTML/CSS/.NET Overflow only one line of table

Tags: .net, html, css, overflow

I will try to be brief/detailed about what i am trying to do here.
I got a table with data fetched from a database.This is a .NET Page. It have 6 columns,with the last one beeing the problematical one. All first 5 columns have little to no info(one line,most of the times, 3 words only). The last column though,will display a whole XML file.

What i am trying to do is:

1. Force the last column (LABELED : INFO) not to be displayed out of
   the TD
2. Overflow the content of this column(INFO),horizontally. Better
   if with the same height of the other lines.

Here is a picture of the current layout:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/85/tablenr.png/

As you can see,the content of the INFO column,is beeing displayed in different heights,according to its need to expand.

What i am trying to,is to force its height to be smaller,and use the horizontal scroll to read the content.

Here is the code snippet.

```
 <div id="dvLogView" runat="server" visible="true">   
     <asp:ListView ID="lvLogs" runat="server" 
        style="margin-left: 9px; margin-top: 27px">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <ul>
                <table border="1" style="width:100%;" class="mainTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th> ID </th>
                        <th> GENERATOR_ </th>
                        <th> DATETIME </th>
                        <th> DBLOGIN </th>
                        <th> INFOTYPE </th>
                        <th> INFO </th>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </table>
                </ul>
            </LayoutTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <tr style="max-height:20px;">
                          <td align="center" style="max-height:20px;"> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "m_ID") %>'></asp:Label> </td>
                          <td align="center" style="max-height:20px;"> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "m_GENERATOR") %>'></asp:Label> </td>
                          <td align="center" style="max-height:20px;"> <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "m_DATETIMESTRING") %>'></asp:Label> </td>
                          <td align="center" style="max-height:20px;"> <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "m_DBLOGIN") %>'></asp:Label> </td>
                          <td align="center" style="max-height:20px;"> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "m_INFOTYPE") %>'></asp:Label> </td>

                          <!-- XML Content -->
                          <td style="max-height:20px; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;"><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "m_INFO") %>'></asp:Label> </td>
                     </tr>  
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

Here is the .MainTable Class being used on the table:

```
.mainTable 
{
table-layout:fixed;
width:400px;
}
```

Sorry for making it long,i tried to be brief and precise.
Thanks in advance,im a layout noob :(

Comment: Have you tried to use a simple `height: #px`?

Comment: @MichaelSazonov Yes,and when i do,this happens : [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/table2x.png/) 

Also tried to fix width,but i couldn´t make it work aswell

Comment: With the `overflow: auto`? Seem a bit strange to me.

Comment: Yes,with the Overflow:auto.

Where should i put this height?
Table ? Tr? Td ?
Also,do i also have to fix the Width? is this "Width 100%" of the table probably messing things up?

Comment: Put into your "info" td `style='width: "DESIRED_WIDTH"px; height "HEIGHT"px; overflow: auto;'`

Comment: @MichaelSazonov Just tried it,exactly how you wrote:
style="width:70px;width:30px;overflow-auto;"

Content of the Info column,still forcing the line to expand.
Like this : [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/40/tableim.png/)

I also removed  layout:fixed from the Class of the table.
Damn,i just dont know whats wrong =/

Comment: `style="width:70px;width:30px;overflow-auto;"` - this is incorrect; `style="width: 70px; height: 30px; overflow: auto;"` is what you're looking for.

Comment: This html is totally invalid.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov My Bad,it was correct in the HTML,but i wrote it incorrectly here.

Rob, Why this is Invalid ?

Comment: Run it through the validator. You cannot place the table or lists as you have them.

Comment: @Rob just runt a HTML Validator for Chrome,and it says its Valid.
Well,nevermind,i will try to figure it out myself.
Thanks again guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the "TD" is the problem.

You can put a DIV with property below inside your TD:

```
style="height: 30px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: scroll;"
```

the code looks like this:

```
<td style="max-height:20px; word-wrap:normal; overflow:auto;">
    <div style="height: 20px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "m_INFO") %>'></asp:Label>
    </div>
</td>
```

Div will scroll vertically and will not be bigger than 30px

Comment: Bullseye !
That was exactly what i wanted,really !

A div inside a table data,damn,looks like inception !
" A dream within a dream"

Answer (score 2):

Is this the behaviour you are looking for?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            .FixedTable{
                table-layout:   fixed; 
                width:          100%;
                border:         1px solid #000000;
            }

            td{
                text-align:     center;
            }

            .LongField{
                height:         20px;
                width:          300px;
                overflow:       hidden;
                text-align:     left;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table  class="FixedTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th class="LongField">Some really long data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>30 November 2011</td>
                    <td>Some other data</td>
                    <td>Mr Name</td>
                    <td class="LongField">Really long fieldname that is aggravatingly pushing out the size of my last column and ruining my life, contributing to disorder, sadness, and increasing entropy in the world</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Add 'white-space:  nowrap;' to .FixedTable for this to work in Chrome btw.

Comment: You can also nest a DIV inside the TD but this is messier. See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569436/css-constrain-a-table-with-long-cell-contents-to-page-width/7570613#7570613

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but it was not exactly what i wanted.
But again,thanks alot for the code provided and for making ot laugh at : 

"Really long fieldname that is aggravatingly pushing out the size of my last column and ruining my life, contributing to disorder, sadness, and increasing entropy in the world"

Comment: Thanks for the vote :-) I strongly suspect that Rob's earlier comment was due to the fact that he validated your source as it was (i.e. before it gets parsed by ASP.Net and output as HTML), which explains the comment about list etc.