# Adjusting a table full width

Tags: css

I would like to format my table like this:

- full width
- columns wider than others can take more place (often the first col)
- columns too large must be cropped (something like overflow: hidden)
- last 2 columns must be narrow than others

Here is a jsFiddle to be more explicit: http://jsfiddle.net/BbNFA/

The problem I encounter here is when all texts in the same line are wider than the width of the page, then a scrollbar is showing. I would like to prevent this by hidden the overflow text.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7570613/446747

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your 2nd and 3rd point? Have you tried using <colgroup>? A width set in % would be more easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** See my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/BbNFA/2/)** here with colgroup.

Use table-layout property and set it to fixed like below,

```
table  { 
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; <-- added
}

td  {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;    <-- added
}
```

Comment: I try it but the result is that every columns have the same width and the first col is overlapping others (see here http://jsfiddle.net/BbNFA/1/).

Comment: why not set the column width with desired values. You can set it for first row/thead and rest of the tr will follow the same width.

Comment: I was searching for another solution than forcing the values... Maybe something is possible, isn't ?

Comment: So is that mean you don't want to specify width? Did you try using <colgroup>?

Comment: @Bronzato Did this answer your question? If yes, please mark it as answered for closure.