# Table exceeds size of div because white space

Tags: css

I'm having a little problem here. Well, I need to prevent the wrap of elements presents in a table, so I use `white-space: nowrap;`. And here is the problem. The table is inside a div:

```
<div class='content'>
    <table>
    <!--Table elements goes here-->
    </table>
</div>
```

In the CSS, I have:

```
div.content
{
    background-color: #E6EBF2;
    padding: 20px;
}
table
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    background-color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
th, td 
{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #D6CECE;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is if the resolution of the screen is small than the table, the width of the div `content` is not expanding according to table size, disfiguring the layout.
My result is something like:
[image]

But it needs to be like this:
[image]

Using `display: inline-block` works, but I can't align the div on center. I apreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: set .content with` width: 100%;`

Comment: @Abdulla, same thing.

Comment: can you upload your table code??

Answer (score 0):

i think in this case, it's either the no-wrap goes... or you just deal with the content going out of bounds of the screen res. No-wrap is doing it's job and so is your width:100%

Comment: Even if the width is not 100% the table goes out of the div. I need to find a way to prevent this, the div width needs to adapt to the table width.

Comment: so then what to do with the cut off content? leave it cut off?

Comment: If I remove the `white-space: nowrap;` the problem goes away, but the elements get wraped and I don't want this.

Comment: Why don't you make that table background by using table border 
 Example: https://jsfiddle.net/m56sphkn
------
<TABLE BORDER=50 BORDERCOLOR=#E6EBF2>

Comment: looks like there's an answer already on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569436/css-constrain-a-table-with-long-cell-contents-to-page-width