# Fixed Height Table, Constrain Large Image inside Table Cell

Tags: css

I have a table with fixed height, and inside I have a table cell with an icon image that needs to be constrained to the height of the table cell. However, no matter what I've tried, the image will either force the table to expand or just ignore the `height: 100%`.

Here is the unmodified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5wxyv9j/) with the initial layout and styling.

Things I have tried based on other SO answers:

- Make sure all parents of `img` have 100% height ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22220780/1852456)): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8rLyncm/1/)
- `table-layout:fixed`, `white-space: nowrap`, and `overflow: hidden` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509825/1852456)): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p3od7j7/1/)
- inner `position: absolute` div to exclude it from layout calculations ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7570613/1852456)): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5defybs/2/)
- inner `float: left` div to exclude it from layout calculations: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p3od7j7/2/)

**Update**:

I'd rather not set the table cell height manually because in the actual layout, the table fits inside a top bar:

[image: top bar]

So all the heights inside the table should be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a cool article on [css flex](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/), turns out its much easier to use for multi-column layouts than a table.

**Solution With One Icon**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wo0t5e0z/)

**Solution With 3 Icons**

```css
.flexcontainer { display: flex; width: 300px; height: 50px; border: 3px solid black }
.column { flex: 1; height: 100%; }
img { height: 100%; width: auto; display: block; margin: auto }
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-icon-set/2133/flat_icons-graficheria.it-13.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-icon-set/2133/flat_icons-graficheria.it-13.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-icon-set/2133/flat_icons-graficheria.it-13.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to give the fixed height to the td element and not to the table? Like so:

```
table tr td { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid black; }
img { display: block; height: 100%; width: auto; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/webmaas/m5wxyv9j/2/

Comment: yeah I mean that was exactly what I was trying to avoid, because the table height is actually from a container. I'll update the question a bit to elaborate

Answer (score 0):

try this, its working at my end

```
img { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

Comment: I use `width: auto` to preserve the aspect ratio of my image. Can you post a JSFiddle link so I can see the entire code?

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

Why does the icon need to be within a table if I may ask?

Comment: this isn't really an answer, I would recommend commenting next time lol, but the reason I used a table is because I need multiple evenly spaced icons, and I thought the easiest way to evenly space things is with table layouts

Comment: Will update my answer with a fix or alternate method once I get home :)